# Visual Studio C++ ARM - build error when using trigonomectric functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arm, .so

I've been making a dynamic library (.so file) for Android in Visual Studio. Recently, I came upon the problem in the title. I tested it with the **asin**, **cos** and **atan2** functions. I tried creating an empty project to see if the error was because of something else in the project, but it persisted. What I find especially strange is that for asin at least, if I make sure that the argument is within the range [-1, 1] like the following, the error stops.

```
double r31 = complicatedAlgorithm();
if (r31 > 1)
    r31 = 1;
if (r31 < -1)
    r31 = -1;
double result = asin(r31);
```

I haven't been able to replicate this behavior with cos and atan2.

### Configuration

- Clang 5.0
- GNU static STL library (does not happen with the default selection but that is not an option for my project)

### Error messages

- Undefined reference to 'asin'
- clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
- Identifier __fp16 undefined (only in main project. In test project I didn't get this, but the behavior is otherwise the same).

### Observations

- The clamp solution for asin does *not* work if no optimization is done by the compiler (-O0 mode)
- If the clamp code is turned into a function that returns the clamped value the error stops, but if the value is passed by reference the error persists.
- Adding the *-mfp16-format=ieee* flag which I saw on the internet causes an unknown argument error.
- **For cos**: If the argument is given directly (e.g. cos(1)) or if it is a variable whose value is known at compile time, no error is thrown.
- Using asinf, cosf and atan2f did not solve the problem.